# How to refactor long list of exported constants defined by the same function to be more DRY

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am currently preparing multiple files containing translation keys where each key is a named export that can be imported into any component within my ReactJS project. I am trying to keep the files as DRY as possible but I am running into an issue with rewriting the same function over and over again to generate the key for each named export and was wondering if there was a cleaner way of writing the function just once.

I have considered exporting a single object containing all of the keys by looping through each key and passing it into the function but this approach will break tree-shaking as I also want to keep my code-split chunks to be as small as possible without importing any unused keys.

```
import { getTranslationKey } from '../../libs/Translation'

const root = "button"
const getButtonKey = (key) => getTranslationKey(root, key)

// each named export will be in the format of root.key e.g. "button.update"
export const BUTTON_UPDATE_KEY = getButtonKey('update')
export const BUTTON_SAVE_KEY = getButtonKey('save')
export const BUTTON_CANCEL_KEY = getButtonKey('cancel')

// more named exports using the getButtonKey arrow function
```